# C# XElement Get Attribute with a Namespace

Tags: c#, linq, attributes, xelement

I have a number of XElements, but their "href" attribute has a namespace. When I try to get it, it returns null.

```
<link xlink:href="The/href" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="a/location">A value</link>
```

I have tried:

```
XElement linkEl = doc.Root.Element("link");
string hrefValue = linkEl.Attribute("href").Value //null;
```

I have also tried adding the namespace to the "href" like "xlink:href" in Attribute(), but this results in an error. Anyone know how to perform this magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sample xml you can't find your element by using its Name it must be the LocalName of the element.

To get element by LocalName here is the sample:

```
var linkElement = doc.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "link").FirstOrDefault();
var linkAttribute = linkElement.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "href").FirstOrDefault();
var hrefValue = linkAttribute.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both great answers! I chose this one because it fits into my workflow of using XPath to find my link elements nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<link xlink:href=""The/href"" xmlns:xlink=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"" xmlns=""a/location"">A value</link>");

XNamespace ab = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
string hrefValue = doc.Root.Attribute(ab + "href").Value;
```